# Do specialties stack?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e

I'm wondering if you have 2 or more specialties that would apply to a roll, do all specialties apply their bonus. For example, if I had a specialty in handguns and revolvers (which is a handgun) and I'm using a revolver, would I receive a +1 or + 2 bonus when using that weapon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Page 150 of the **God Machine Chronicle**:

> You may only purchase one instance of a given Specialty, although *multiple Specialties may apply to a given roll*. For example, Surgery and Cardiology may apply to a Medicine roll to perform heart surgery.

Page 37 of **The World of Darkness, 1e** (and not superseded in GMC)

> Specialty: An area of Skill expertise in which a character excels. Whenever a Specialty applies to a character’s task, one die is added to his player’s dice pool.

So, if "multiple specialties may apply to a given roll" and "whenever a Specialty applies…one die is added," that adds up to "multiple relevant specialties add multiple dice." If you've spent two Specialties to be grand at "handguns" and "revolvers" (although as a Storyteller I'd look askance at that, since "revolver" is usually a subset of "handgun," barring novelties and historical curiosities), then you get your +2 dice. It's a reasonable benefit for the cost.

Comment: [These come to mind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolver#Revolving_long_guns)

Comment: @Pureferret Okay. I have learned of a new thing. If I knew more about firearms, I could figure out whether revolver shotguns should share a specialty with revolver pistols or with the other kinds of shotguns. As I do not, I'd still probably look askance, but with less skepticism.

Comment: I can't blame you. I looked some up a while back. I'd still be doubtful (like you) of allowing this.